# Snowpark: Using a variable (values in a column from another table) to perform a dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a one table from which I want to extract the value from a JSON column (JSON_TABLE).

The JSON values I want to extract have different identifiers but are at the same level. I have another table, which has the same amount of rows as the first and contains all the identifiers (one column): IDENTIFER_TABLE. Here's a sample of the data (first row is the column name):

[image: IDENTIFIER TABLE]

So, I want to use the second table to form a dynamic sql query. I've tried the following:

```
identifier = session.sql("SELECT * FROM identifier_table)

dynamic_table = session.sql(f"""SELECT streaming_data:data:{identifier} FROM 
JSON_TABLE""")
```

I get the following error:

```
snowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSQLException: 1304): 01b119fb-0303-3b1d-0000-4bf137b626a2: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 27 unexpected '<'.
syntax error line 1 at position 74 unexpected 'at'.
```

The error doesn't really make sense given my code. I did previous use this but I deleted it (so no idea why I'm still getting this same error):

```
dataframe = session.sql('SELECT streaming_data, 
streaming_data:position::string AS property FROM JSON_TABLE, 
lateral flatten (INPUT => streaming_data)')
```

To be honest, I've less concerned about the error and more concerned with whether my underlying logic/ method is sound. If so, will try this code on a different platform.

I've also tried doing by converting identifier table from a snowspark df to a pandas df and then to a list. However, it hasn't worked.

It works if I hard-coded a value (but as expected, generates NULL for rows which it doesn't match).

For the desired output, I want to return the same values in the identifier table (in that order) by referencing the table as a  variable - Selecting from the JSON table. So, after it's written back to Snowflake it's a two column table with both the identifiers and JSON values. Also, I don't want to just stick them together (through some kind of join) as I want to know how to create this output using a dynamic query.

Comment: your first sql are missing a double quote and the provoded code doesn't match your error

Comment: Apologies, my mistake in copying the code. Not present in the worksheet and not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by math my error?

Comment: i mean match your error  there is no < in that code

Comment: I know, that's why I'm so confused. I did have it previously, as I used that to flatten it. I originally had this:     dataframe = session.sql('SELECT streaming_data, streaming_data:position::string  AS property FROM JSON_TABLE, lateral flatten (INPUT => streaming_data)')

Comment: then he processes the other command, add your old command to the question

Comment: I didn't. I've deleted it, but still get this error. Maybe it's problem with my sheet- I don't know. By posting this, I'm hoping I get some feedback as to whether my underlying logic is correct? If so, I will try this same code in a different environment (using a Snowflake python sheet right now).

Comment: it was not clear in your question, you nned to add all information that will help

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment but was too long therefore posting as an answer.

First, your initial Dataframe has no action (like `collect` for example):

```
identifier = session.sql("SELECT * FROM identifier_table)
```

therefore the above would only return a Snowpark object like this:

```
<snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame object at 0xffffxxxxxxx>
```

This in return will make your next query to look like this:

```
SELECT streaming_data:data:<snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame object at 0xffffxxxxxx> FROM JSON_TABLE
```

This in return will cause the error you are posting.

The easiest way to see this issue is to go on Snowflake UI at Query History and check your query id that is shown in the error `01b119fb-0303-3b1d-0000-4bf137b626a2`.

Now, depending how your table `identifier_table` is defined I would not do a `SELECT *` but maybe only the column I need and are you sure it is returning one row only?

So you should have something like this:

```
identifier = session.sql("SELECT identifier FROM identifier_table).collect()
```

Now if you print `identifier` you should have a value for it (or multiple if you have multiple rows). You will still need to get the values out since `identifier` is a dataframe so something like this:

```
identifier['IDENTIFIER'].iloc[0]
```

where `IDENTIFIER` is the name of the column and `identifier` is the name of the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. So, I've used .collect() but I'm still getting this error: syntax error line 1 at position 96 unexpected 'IDENTIFIER'.
syntax error line 1 at position 106 unexpected '='. I'm guessing I need to turn it into a list first but whenever I've tried that (by first converting to pandas), it just doesn't work. No error but I get NULL values.

Comment: The `identifier` is still a dataframe object, so you need to take the value only out of it. Something like `identifier['IDENTIFIER'].iloc[0]` where `IDENTIFIER` is the name of the column and `identifier` is the name of the dataframe.

Comment: Strangely, I get this: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Definitely didn't put quote marks around the number.

Comment: Just do `identifier.show()` to see how the dataframe looks like as first step.